# Servlet encoding woes in Open Liberty

Tags: java, servlets, websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I have a simple test servlet that should output a non ASCII character (right single quotation mark - ’).  In Tomcat, it works, but in Liberty I get junk.  Is this a bug in Liberty, am I doing it wrong, or a config issue?

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.print("’");
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and the web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test.TestServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/TestServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

From **Tomcat** the response is (courtesy of Fiddler):

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 3
Date: Wed, 23 Jun 2021 23:40:07 GMT

’
```

The body hex is: E2, 80, 99 (which is correct UTF-8 for ’)

From **Liberty** it is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 3
Content-Language: en-CA
Date: Wed, 23 Jun 2021 23:52:49 GMT

â€™
```

The hex for that content is: C3, A2, E2, 82, AC, E2, 84, A2

Dev tools (F12) matches Fiddler.

I've tried moving around the code

```
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

before and after the getWriter (the docs say it should be before getWriter).  With and without `setCharacterEncoding` and all kinds of things, content types etc.

The .java file itself is saved with UTF-8 encoding.

It's curious that the content length header says 3 bytes with either server, but with Liberty the actual content length is 8 bytes.  As if the bytes have been re-encoded?

So, what is going on here?

**UPDATE:**  taking out the out.close() per @pmdinh's answer had an effect, but didn't fix it.  This is the closest I could get to proper behaviour

```
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");    
            
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");    
        
        out.print("’1234");

    }
```

This correctly **encodes** it, but now the content length is wrong by 2 bytes.  So the response is

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 5
Content-Language: en-CA
Date: Thu, 24 Jun 2021 17:50:55 GMT

’1234
```

but since the content-length is 2 short the browser shows `’12`

Also note that the placing of setCharacterEncoding and setContentType matters and other combinations make the output even worse (incorrect encoding).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the

```
out.close();
```

that should resolve the issue.

Ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/PM71666

Comment: Thanks. That definitely has an effect, but doesn't resolve it.  Will update question with my observations.

Comment: Guess what try-with-resources statement does. Get rid of it as well. You don't need it on resources not created by your code.